# how to send a value from a widget to another on the same screen ? (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement a slider that add a certain value to the initial value when checking out.
But I'm not able to pass that extra value to my checkout API Call.

Here an example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwWQE.jpg

My slider is implemented inside a StatefullWidget called DonationView like this:

```
Widget getSlider(BuildContext context) {
    return Slider(
      min: 0,
      max: 2000,
      value: widget.extra.toDouble(),
      onChanged: ((value) {
        setState(() {
          widget.extra = value.toInt();
        });
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to pass the value "extra" to the api call fetchStripePaymentIntent

```
class DonateScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int itemId;
  final int conversationId;
  final int extraInCent;

  DonateScreen(@pathParam this.itemId, @pathParam this.conversationId, @pathParam this.extraInCent,
      {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DonateScreenState createState() => _DonateScreenState();
}

class _DonateScreenState extends State<DonateScreen> {
  late Future<StripePaymentIntent> _stripePaymentIntent;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      _stripePaymentIntent = Provider.of<PaymentIntentProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .fetchStripePaymentIntent(widget.itemId, widget.extraInCent);
    });
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ItemBloc, ItemState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is ItemLoadedState) {
          Item item = state.item;
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(
                "Pay".tr(),
              ),
            ),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: BlocBuilder<ProfileBloc, ProfileState>(
                builder: ((context, state) {
                  if (state is ProfileLoadedState) {
                    UserProfile userProfile = state.userProfile;
                    return FutureBuilder<StripePaymentIntent>(
                        future: _stripePaymentIntent,
                        builder:
                            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<StripePaymentIntent> snapshot) {
                          List<Widget> children;
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            Item theItem = item;
                            children = <Widget>[
                              BlocBuilder<NgosBloc, NgosState>(
                                builder: (context, state) {
                                  if (state is NgosLoadedState) {
                                    return Column(
                                      children: [
                                        DonateView(
                                          snapshot.data!,
                                          theItem,
                                          userProfile,
                                          widget.conversationId,
                                          state.ngos[item.ngoId]!,
                                          widget.extraInCent,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  }
                                  return Container();
                                },
                              ),
                            ];
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Please, provide more information about the app flow.

Comment: @Wiktor I won't have enough space here to explain everything, but this might be helpful https://pastebin.com/rqP6i0XW

Answer (score 0):

```
setState(() {
    widget.extra = value.toInt();
});
```

This seems weird. Widget members should be `final`. In `setState()`, you usually update members of the enclosing `State` class.

To share values between widgets outside of the same `State`, you should check out [state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro). It's essential.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, just to tell you that I'm already using Bloc as my State manager and that I already solved my problem :)